# What is this plant that is like 6 inches in height and fresh in the last 2 months?

Tags: identification

I had planted a couple of seeds a few months ago. One of them was tomato and I see a tomato plant. The other one, I can't remember and it has grown to be this.

Can you please let me know what plant this is? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks a bit like Galium odoratum - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galium_odoratum